# Adding a Breadcrumbs php to my Bootstrap Nav Bar

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap Nav bar intially had a `<ul>` tag with link. I decided to replace it with a breadcrumbs. Since it's a php file used as a header, it's php code for the breadcrumbs, placed in a `<div>` using the same class as the previous `<uL>`. I still have another `<ul>`that pulls right.

The issue I am having is that the breadcrumbs are loading at the very top of my browser and the `<uL>`is loading where it should.

```html
<div class="container">
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
       
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
   <?php 
      $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
         $parts = explode('/',$path);
      if (count($parts) < 2){
      echo("home");
      }
      else {
 echo ("<a href=\"/\">home</a> &raquo; ");
 for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
     {
     if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
         {
         echo("<a href=\"");
         for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
         echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i])."</a> » ");
         }
     else
         {
          $str = $parts[$i];
         $pos = strrpos($str,".");
         $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
         echo str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i]);
         };
     };
 };  
?>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink1']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption1'); ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink2']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption2'); ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink3']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption3'); ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink4']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption4'); ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink5']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption5'); ?></a></li>
        </ul>-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink6']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption6'); ?></a></li>
        
     <li><?php
     if(!$currentuser) {
      if(!$tngconfig['disallowreg'])
       echo "<li><a href=\"newacctform.php\">{$text['mnuregister']}</a></li>\n";
      echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\">{$text['mnulogon']}</a></li>\n";
     }
     else {
      echo "<li><a href=\"logout.php\">{$text['mnulogout']}</a></li>\n";
     }
     ?></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink7']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption7'); ?></a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo $tmp['t100_navlink8']; ?>"><?php echo getTemplateMessage('t100_navoption8'); ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    
      </nav>
</div>
```

you can see what I mean if you go to [example](http://www.mariahswind.com/TNGSandBox/surnames.php) requires login use guest and guest to login. This loads at the top above jumbotron on all pages except the index.php

(For those interested my project is customizing with Bootstrap the output php pages of my TNG (The Next Generation of Genealogy Site Building) site.)

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Is the problem that the breadcrumbs are at a different height from the navigation?

Comment: yes that is the problem @maximo. I will be exploring the answer provided by Martin. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  tags in the ul get a padding of 15px which is why they are slightly lower on the page, you can add an extra class:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav breadcrumb-nav">
     <?php 
       .....
     ?>
</div>
```

and add this to your css

```
.breadcrumb-nav {
   padding: 15px;
}
```

You could also change your PHP to generate the bootstrap breadcrumbs http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs

Comment: thank you! both options are great. I wasn't thorough enough in my search on the bootstrap site for breadcrumbs.

Comment: I combined both do achieve satisfactory results. Again many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use breadcrumb with php like this

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><?php .... ?></a></li>
   <li class="active"><?php ... ?></li>
</ol>
```